# Make iMac file structure more like windows

Tags: mac, windows, accessibility

I am a web developer that works for a company and I am looking to make my Mac feel more like windows. I am having trouble navigating the file system, I am colorblind and the files are all blue and small (I am most sensitive to blue when it comes to not seeing right).

How can I customize my Mac for increased visibility and increased font sizes?

Comment: I have used Mac for 10+ years, and I don't know what you mean by 'blue and small'. None of my machines (Lion, Mavericks) have files that are blue and small. Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: I believe he's referring to the folder icons.

Comment: yes I am referring to the folder icons. I was speaking with a coworker and we just realized that there is no highlight on hover for navigation. It feels "floaty".

Comment: Why would you highlight icons on hover?  If you want to select something just click on it, if you want to select multiple items, click and drag over it.

Comment: If you want to upload a screen shot of what you want the files to look like that would help people advise you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Finder window, choose Show View Options from the View menu. Here you can change the icon and text size of items. Click "Use as Defaults" when you're happy with it.

Open System Preferences from the Apple menu and then click General. You can set the highlight color to another color besides blue. Check out the other options here as well.

Finally, still in System Preferences, click Show All and then click Accessibility. Try upping the contrast and exploring the other options here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the color of the folders in OSX, unfortunately Apple thinks they should be blue. You can use different views to make them nearly any size you like, especially if you choose the icon view.

However, if you want to change the color of the folders, I recommend an app called Folder Magic, that allows you to change the folders to any color you wish:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folder-magic/id647731944?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of icons in Finder hit command-J (or navigate to View->Show View Options).  There will be a slider bar with icon size there, make them as big as you want.

To change the default folder icons, you can use a program like CandyBar http://www.panic.com/blog/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/ to change the default folder icon for all folders.